# Get content of password protected URL with Java 8

Tags: java, authentication

I successfully wrote Java programs that get the content of an URL through BufferedReader and InputStreamReader classes.
But this time, I need to access an URL that is password protected, and I am stuck. I have found examples that use the Authenticator class and its setDefault static method, but, although it is mentioned in the Java 8 documentation, Eclipse tells me that *The method setDefault(Authenticator) is undefined for the type Authenticator*.

Could you please put me on the right track?

Note: I am using JRE 1.8.0_25.

Comment: Well spotted! I indeed had imported the wrong Authenticator class. Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java API, that should work if you are using `java.net.Authenticator`